# Set property in gremlin-node.js/gremlin-server not working

Tags: node.js, gremlin

I want to create a graph within gremlin-server from a node.js backend with the javascript driver of gremlin. As I added two properties, one id and one username, the id is working, the username is not stored. Here is the code:

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');

const traversal = gremlin.process.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;

const g = traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'));

const { t: { id } } = gremlin.process;
const { cardinality: { single} } = gremlin.process;

    async function createUser(userid,username) {
        const vertex = await
            g.addV('User')
            .property(id,userid)
            .property(single,'username',username)
            .iterate();
        return vertex;
    }
await createUser(1001,"testuser")
```

The output is (when I search the node with `g.V(1001).listAll();`) The properties are always `undefined`.

```
[Vertex { id: 1001, label: 'User', properties: undefined }]
```

The gremlin server was loaded/run with docker with the following commands:

- `docker pull tinkerpop/gremlin-server`
- `docker run -d -p 8182:8182 --name gremlin tinkerpop/gremlin-server`
- The gremlin-driver in node.js has a the version: `"gremlin": "^3.4.10",`

I've tried with and without the cardinality single above, added more properties, but non is working. The internet searches showed some gremlin-console(groovy) working examples with the `.property` step, but no hint for the combination node.js-driver of gremlin and the gremlin-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your code is working fine and that the properties are present. The issue is that graph elements returned from queries are "references" only - meaning, they only include id and label and no properties. You should convert your results to use generic containers like `Map` using a step like `elementMap()`. You can find more discussion on this in the documentation in various places, but perhaps start with [this](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_properties_of_elements) and if you are interested more in why this is the way it is and what challenges are involved in changing it, please see [this](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/e959e85d4f8b3d46d281f2742a6e574c7d27c54bfc52f802f7c04af3%40%3Cdev.tinkerpop.apache.org%3E).

Comment: Hi Stephen, you are right: a `g.V(id).elementMap().toList()` is showing apart from the id and the label also the property `'username' => 'testuser'`. Thank you a lot.